# Can't insert to database jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I can't insert or edit records with this.

My SQLException has an error "Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"
Am new to java so everything is a learning process

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String forward = "";
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {
            int surveyid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("survey_id"));
            firstdao.removeFirst(surveyid);
            forward = list_first;
            try {
                request.setAttribute("firsts", firstdao.getFirst());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
            forward = insert_or_edit;
            int surveyid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("survey_id"));
            try {
                First first = firstdao.getFirstById(surveyid);
                request.setAttribute("first", first);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listFirst")) {
            forward = list_first;
            try {
                request.setAttribute("firsts", firstdao.getFirst());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            forward = insert_or_edit;
        }
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

FirstController.java

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static String insert_or_edit = "/first.jsp";
private static String list_first = "/listfirst.jsp";
private FirstDAO firstdao; 
public FirstController() {
super();
firstdao = new FirstDAO();
}
```

FirstDAO.java

```
public void addFirst(First first) {
try {
String query = "insert into survey_data_27 (uname, p1q1, p1q2, p1q3, p1q4) values('"+ first.getuname() +"', '"+ first.getp1q1() +"', '"+ first.getp1q2() +"', '"+ first.getp1q3() +"', '"+ first.getp1q4() +"')";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
} catch (SQLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `firstdao`?

Comment: i've added the FirstController and FirstDAO

Comment: Why don't you use PreparedStatement ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you catch the SQL-Exception in your DAO class it is not visible in your servlet. That's why you can not catch it there. So you have to removen the

```
try { 
    ... 
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

blocks from your servlet.

Also you should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your edit method can never throw a SQLException, since it doesn't declare it in a throws clause. Therefore, your catch clause in servlet is unreachable.

You don't need to throw SQLException from the edit method, but you also don't need to surround the call to edit with a try block and you don't need to catch SQLException.